# Binding buttons together android in eclipse

Tags: android

Hi im creating a app(school project) that's going to have five buttons with one color each.
Red, yellow, blue, white, black.

This is a game for children, first they will see a image that's just white, they will get instructions to paint it by combining colors

When I for example want green I click yellow and blue and the image is going to change to green.

My problem is that I want to handle the clicks.. If I click first the yellow button it´s going to save some how and then when I click blue the image will change. But if they click the wrong combination a sound will play.. and then resten the buttons..

I don't want a whole solution just a point in the right direction.. so i can start coding this

Comment: At the first button click, put a (corresponding) value in an int variable (1,2,3,4,5) then when you click the other button you know the value of that variable and see if it matches (and then reset the variable to 0, so you know that next click is the "first" button click). You could use **bitmasks**, but I don't want to complicate your life.

Answer (score 1):

For simple applications you can just use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to store the state with the buttons that have been pressed.

In your touch event listener you call some method in your Singleton object to keep track of the previous presses.

Comment: What advantage would a Singleton have over just tracking the presses with fields in the fragment?

Comment: Well you might need to swap fragments or activities but also retain the state of the buttons that have been pressed. If you don't then just track the button presses in an array or something to keep it simple

Comment: Not having the data in the Fragment gives a separation of logic and presentation and also works if the app has several Fragments. I would also recommend having some more high level public methods in the Singleton to make it easy to change the implementation of the logic and how the data is stored.